# Warning comparsion between pointer and string

Tags: c, string, pointers, integer

I want to input a string and if it contains two consecutive "HH" in it then it should print out "voila" to the screen if it does not contain it should return "No voila"

```
int main()
{   

 char str[100];
 printf("Enter string");      
 scanf("%s",str);   

for (i=0;i<strlen(str); i++)
{


    if (str[i] && str[i+1] == "HH" )
    {
        printf("voila");
    }
    else{
        printf("No voila");
    }

 }
return 0;
 }
```

If a string is scanned and if it contains two consecutive "H" it should print out voila

The warning I get is comparison between pointer and integer
Please rectify my code as I am a beginner in c.
Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: I don't think that `str[i] == "HH"` does what you expect it to do

Comment: Use `strcmp(str, "HH") == 0` instead. Voilà.

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: @RingØ: That will not work.

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> if it contains two consecutive "HH" then it should print out "voila" to the screen

I assume you mean two consecutive `H`s, not two consecutive `"HH"`s.

For the first, you would need to look for `"HH"` while for the latter, you would need to look for `"HHHH"`.

In either case, you need to use [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr).

```
if ( strstr(str, "HH") != NULL ) 
{
    printf("voila");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`"HH"` this is string literal and when we use it in the comparison the address of it is compared with the ascii value of the character `str[i]` is being compared. That's why you got the warning message.

Solution would be to use `strcmp(str,"HH")==0` then print voila.(As this means `str` matches with `"HH"`).

You don't need the loop here. So you would simply do this

```
if( strcmp(str,"HH") == 0)
    printf("voila");
else
    printf("No voila");
```

#### Edit:(Missed the part two consecutive occurence of `HH`)

Again if you need to find the consecutive occurence then this solution wouldn't work because this matches exactly the content. Then you need to use `strstr` or similar function which finds the occurence of a substring in a string.

From standard 7.24.5.7

```
 char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

> The strstr function locates the first occurrence in the string pointed
>   to by `s1` of the sequence of characters (excluding the terminating null
>   character) in the string pointed to by `s2`.
>   The `strstr` function returns a pointer to the located string, or a **null
>   pointer if the string is not found**.

#### Without any function:

To find the single occurence you can also do this

```
for(size_t  i = 0;  i<=strlen(str)-2; i++)
    if( str[i] == 'H' && str[i+1] == 'H'){
       printf("Voila");
       return 0;
    }
printf("No voila");
return 0;
```

Notice that we are comparing with `'H'` the character not the literal `"H"`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
for (i=0;i<strlen(str); i++)
{    
    int flag=0;
    if (str[i] == "H" )
    {
       if(flag>0)
       {
        printf("voila");
       } else {
          flag++;
       }
    } else {
       flag=0;
       printf("No voila");
    }
 }
```

Comment: What about the string `"HHH"`? Oh, that qualifies (didn't read the Q carefully). But you may have anumber of mixed "voila / no voila" (eg "ABHHDEHH")... Try to fix that (eg by counting the max number of consecutive 'H', and only display the message after the loop)

Answer (score 0):

this should help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{


char str[100];
printf("Enter string");

scanf("%s",str);
int flag = 0;

for (int i=0;i<strlen(str) - 1; i++)
{


    if (str[i] == 'H' && str[i+1] == 'H')
    {

        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
 }

if (flag){
    printf("voila");
}
else {
    printf("no voila");
}
return 0;
 }
```

The warning you were getting, was because you were comparing `char` at a time with `string HH` on line `str[i] == "HH"`

Comment: This will not work if the input contains a space followed by `HH`.